# Flow commands lead to Doctrine Database Exception

Tags: doctrine-orm, typo3-flow, neoscms

I have installed NEOS 1.2.1 via composer,created a new site, everything is dandy.
but after a while i ran across an error where neos told me to use node:repair 
okay i did, but with that i ran afoul of the following exception.
it seems it cannot connect or something like that *scratches head*
My question is why,when other flow commands (presumably without the DB) were executed just fine?

This is running local on Mac with Mamp Pro, does have anyone an idea, what causes this?

```
    TombStone:source lucither$ ./flow node:repair --node-type TYPO3.Neos.NodeTypes:Page

    Uncaught Exception: TYPO3\Flow\Persistence\Doctrine\Exception\DatabaseConnectionException

    Message
      SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

    More Information
      Exception code 2002
      File           /Users/lucither/development/XXX/source/Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/TYPO3_Flow_Persistence_Doctrine_Query.php line 230
      Reference code 20150106214706a2dfc2

    Stack trace

    #0 TYPO3\Flow\Persistence\Doctrine\Query_Original::count()
       /Users/lucither/development/XXX/source/Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/TYPO3_Flow_Persistence_Doctrine_Query.php:794

    #1 TYPO3\Flow\Persistence\Doctrine\Query::count()

    #2 ::call_user_func_array()
       /Users/lucither/development/XXX/source/Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/TYPO3_Flow_Persistence_Doctrine_Query.php:745

    #3 TYPO3\Flow\Persistence\Doctrine\Query::Flow_Aop_Proxy_invokeJoinPoint()
       /Users/lucither/development/XXX/source/Packages/Framework/TYPO3.Flow/Classes/TYPO3/Flow/Aop/Advice/AdviceChain.php:57

    #4 TYPO3\Flow\Aop\Advice\AdviceChain::proceed()
       /Users/lucither/development/XXX/source/Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/TYPO3_Flow_Security_Aspect_PersistenceQueryRewritingAspect.php:102

    #5 TYPO3\Flow\Security\Aspect\PersistenceQueryRewritingAspect_Original::rewriteQomQuery()
       /Users/lucither/development/XXX/source/Packages/Framework/TYPO3.Flow/Classes/TYPO3/Flow/Aop/Advice/AroundAdvice.php:34

    #6 TYPO3\Flow\Aop\Advice\AroundAdvice::invoke()
       /Users/lucither/development/XXX/source/Packages/Framework/TYPO3.Flow/Classes/TYPO3/Flow/Aop/Advice/AdviceChain.php:55

    #7 TYPO3\Flow\Aop\Advice\AdviceChain::proceed()
       /Users/lucither/development/XXX/source/Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/TYPO3_Flow_Persistence_Doctrine_Query.php:806

    #8 TYPO3\Flow\Persistence\Doctrine\Query::count()
       /Users/lucither/development/XXX/source/Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/TYPO3_Flow_Persistence_Doctrine_QueryResult.php:87

    #9 TYPO3\Flow\Persistence\Doctrine\QueryResult_Original::count()
       /Users/lucither/development/XXX/source/Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/TYPO3_TYPO3CR_Command_NodeCommandController.php:95

    #10 TYPO3\TYPO3CR\Command\NodeCommandController_Original::repairCommand()

    #11 ::call_user_func_array()
       /Users/lucither/development/XXX/source/Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/TYPO3_Flow_Cli_CommandController.php:240

    #12 TYPO3\Flow\Cli\CommandController_Original::callCommandMethod()
       /Users/lucither/development/XXX/source/Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/TYPO3_Flow_Cli_CommandController.php:110

    #13 TYPO3\Flow\Cli\CommandController_Original::processRequest()
       /Users/lucither/development/XXX/source/Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/TYPO3_Flow_Mvc_Dispatcher.php:80

    #14 TYPO3\Flow\Mvc\Dispatcher_Original::dispatch()
       /Users/lucither/development/XXX/source/Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/TYPO3_Flow_Mvc_Dispatcher.php:298

    #15 TYPO3\Flow\Mvc\Dispatcher::dispatch()

    #16 ::call_user_func_array()
       /Users/lucither/development/XXX/source/Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/TYPO3_Flow_Mvc_Dispatcher.php:282

    #17 TYPO3\Flow\Mvc\Dispatcher::Flow_Aop_Proxy_invokeJoinPoint()
       /Users/lucither/development/XXX/source/Packages/Framework/TYPO3.Flow/Classes/TYPO3/Flow/Aop/Advice/AdviceChain.php:57

    #18 TYPO3\Flow\Aop\Advice\AdviceChain::proceed()
       /Users/lucither/development/XXX/source/Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/TYPO3_Flow_Security_Aspect_RequestDispatchingAspect.php:75

    #19 TYPO3\Flow\Security\Aspect\RequestDispatchingAspect_Original::blockIllegalRequestsAndForwardToAuthenticationEntryPoints()
       /Users/lucither/development/XXX/source/Packages/Framework/TYPO3.Flow/Classes/TYPO3/Flow/Aop/Advice/AroundAdvice.php:34

    #20 TYPO3\Flow\Aop\Advice\AroundAdvice::invoke()
       /Users/lucither/development/XXX/source/Packages/Framework/TYPO3.Flow/Classes/TYPO3/Flow/Aop/Advice/AdviceChain.php:55

    #21 TYPO3\Flow\Aop\Advice\AdviceChain::proceed()
       /Users/lucither/development/XXX/source/Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/TYPO3_Flow_Mvc_Dispatcher.php:313

    #22 TYPO3\Flow\Mvc\Dispatcher::dispatch()
       /Users/lucither/development/XXX/source/Packages/Framework/TYPO3.Flow/Classes/TYPO3/Flow/Cli/CommandRequestHandler.php:97

    #23 TYPO3\Flow\Cli\CommandRequestHandler::handleRequest()
       /Users/lucither/development/XXX/source/Packages/Framework/TYPO3.Flow/Classes/TYPO3/Flow/Core/Bootstrap.php:108

    #24 TYPO3\Flow\Core\Bootstrap::run()
       /Users/lucither/development/XXX/source/Packages/Framework/TYPO3.Flow/Scripts/flow.php:55

    #25 ::require()
       /Users/lucither/development/XXX/source/flow:18
```

Comment: Found the Solution. flow did use the inbuilt php of Mac OS X and php.ini, not the MAMP version.

Comment: oops time limit on edit so again:Found the Solution. flow did use the inbuilt php of Mac OS X and php.ini, not the MAMP version.

After i set the PATH inside my .bash_profile  to `PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH`

everything worked. Sorry for the bother.
Hope this will be of use for someone else.